# Select records within range of dates in Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Given a table `concerts` and a column `concerts.occurence_dates` of `Array` type.
I need to select concerts which occurs within `from_date` and `to_date`  using ActiveRecord.

I just figured out how to select events after `from_date`:

```
Concert.where(':from_date < ANY(occurrence_dates)', from_date: from_date)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution:

```
Concert.where('(occurrence_dates[0], occurrence_dates[array_length(occurrence_dates, 1)]) OVERLAPS (:from_date, :to_date)', from_date: from_date, to_date: to_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned in the official documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html)

> Arrays are not sets; searching for specific array elements can be a sign of database misdesign. Consider using a separate table with a row for each item that would be an array element. This will be easier to search, and is likely to scale better for a large number of elements.

This also applies to your case, trying to perform a search using specific array elements.

You are using the wrong field. What you really need to use are two separate columns, one for the `from_date` and the other for the `to_date`, along with two indexes.

The indexes will ensure a fast lookup, the separate columns will allow you to search passing a range of dates or simply using

```
Concert.where('from_date >= ? AND to_date <= ?', from_date, to_date)
```

With the current setup, your best solution is to scan all the records, select each `occurrence_dates` and check whether they match your criteria.

Comment: what if I'm not a DB owner and have it as a legacy?